# Is safe to reinstall Ubuntu if I have broken Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.04

What will happen if I have dual boot, Windows in sda4,sda5 and Ubuntu on sda6? I want tp reinstall Ubuntu, because [OS Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) ruined my boot manager. It is possible to delete sda4 and sda5 but save sda6 and reinstall Ubuntu?

The reason for reinstalling is because with my current Ubuntu, Ubuntu freezes at the Ubuntu logo screen.

I found the reason why Ubuntu was frozen at the Ubuntu logo at boot, it was in the file `/etc/fstab`. In the forum it was written that it is necessary to uncomment the lines in it 9 and 13, it's the file itself:
https://pastebin.com/WYL407bv.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=aedc7ae6-8b90-4a89-8edc-cc73f074257c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=F869-31A3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=F869-31A3  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

After the reboot, I was thrown into the emergency mode, in it I through `nano /etc/fstab` commented on the same lines 9 and 13 and successfully loaded the system.

After loading, you must again uncompress 9 and 13 lines. This procedure should always be done when leaving the computer, and then again hangs when the Ubuntu logo appears.

Comment: pretty sure you can create another one partition at reinstalling Ubuntu, so it will make 2 Ubuntu partitions, and removing the 2 Windows partitions can be done after installation (not sure you can select partition that you want to erase in Ubuntu installer)

Comment: i can create another partition when install ubuntu from live usb??

Comment: as is say, i'm pretty sure it's possible, it will be placed on sda7

Comment: in this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver if i choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" , it will delete sda4,sda5 and sda6??

Comment: yes, as it's write "it will delete all your programs [...] in all your OS" so yes, sda4-5-6 deleted; in your case, you must use the bottom one "Something elese"

Comment: The problem description is not clear. Is the problem that you wish to wipe all the other partitions and use Ubuntu only on this system? Is the problem a broken  bootloader? Is the problem a broken install that must be 'decompressed' each time?  Without a complete understanding of the problem, many experts here will refuse to offer a solution. Partial hacks often just make things worse.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have decided reinstall ubuntu with erase disk.